# Travis: gpg: signing failed: secret key not available

Tags: maven, travis-ci, gnupg, openpgp

I try to deploy my opensource project to Nexus Repository (https://oss.sonatype.org) using the travis ci, but unfortunately travis doesn't found the secret key for gpg signed step.

I follow all steps on https://github.com/making/travis-ci-maven-deploy-skelton but the release deploy continuous doesn't work. At my workspace all works correctly and I can deploy releases to Nexus Repository.

I'm using one script to deploy the project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Checking the current branch..."
if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = 'master' ] && [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == 'false' ]; then
   echo "The current branch is: master"
   echo "Run maven deploy parameter using sign and build-extras profiles..."
   mvn deploy -P sign,build-extras --settings setting-maven.xml
fi
```

Comment: What `setting.xml`/`pom.xml` file are you using? You have to set the properties `gpg.defaultKeyring` to `false` and `gpg.publicKeyring` to your public keying and `gpg.secretKeyring` to your secret keyring. See https://github.com/making/travis-ci-maven-deploy-skelton/blob/master/README.md The sample code requires, that you have set the env variable `GPG_DIR` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Such issues commonly occur if the service is running under another user than the developer's account. GnuPG has per-user "GnuPG home directories" in `~/.gnupg`. Make sure to import the keys under the service's user (run this command from your developer account):

```
gpg --export-secret-keys [key-id] | sudo -u [service user] gpg --import
```

Alternatively, you could use `gpg`'s `--homedir` option to change to GnuPG home directory location, but be aware GnuPG is very picky about properly set, tight permissions by default (which is a good thing).

Answer (score 1):

The solution in https://github.com/making/travis-ci-maven-deploy-skelton relies on symmetrically encrypted keyrings in your `$GPG_DIR`. In the sample that would be the folder `deploy`.

To create these keyrings, you do this (copied):

```
$ export ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=<password to encrypt>
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD -in ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg -out deploy/secring.gpg.enc
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD -in ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg -out deploy/pubring.gpg.enc
```

This creates the encrypted keyrings in the folder `deploy`. You probably need to create the folder before you run the `openssl` commands.
Both encrypted keyrings need to be checked in, so that they are available as part of the project at build-time.

At build-time you need to decrypt the keyrings. You do this by adding something like this to your `.travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD -in $GPG_DIR/pubring.gpg.enc -out $GPG_DIR/pubring.gpg -d
- openssl aes-256-cbc -pass pass:$ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD -in $GPG_DIR/secring.gpg.enc -out $GPG_DIR/secring.gpg -d
```

Note, how the `openssl` command uses `$GPG_DIR`? That's basically your `deploy` directory. To make sure Travis knows about `$GPG_DIR`, define it, e.g. like this:

```
env:
  global:
  - GPG_DIR="`pwd`/deploy"
```

So basically Travis now knows how to decrypt your GPG keyrings and puts them into a defined location. Now you still have to tell GPG how to pick it up. For that you have two options:

1. Properties in your `pom.xml` or
2. properties in your `settings.xml`

The project https://github.com/making/travis-ci-maven-deploy-skelton uses the first option (`pom.xml`). The essential part is:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <properties>
            <gpg.executable>gpg</gpg.executable>
            <gpg.keyname>${env.GPG_KEYNAME}</gpg.keyname>
            <gpg.passphrase>${env.GPG_PASSPHRASE}</gpg.passphrase>

            <!-- tell gpg to NOT use the default keyring from the current user's home -->
            <gpg.defaultKeyring>false</gpg.defaultKeyring>

            <!-- instead tell gpg to use the keyrings from your GPG_DIR -->
            <gpg.publicKeyring>${env.GPG_DIR}/pubring.gpg</gpg.publicKeyring>
            <gpg.secretKeyring>${env.GPG_DIR}/secring.gpg</gpg.secretKeyring>
        </properties>
        [...]
```

With these properties you define parameters for the `gpg` executable. This works, because you have set up `$GPG_DIR` in your `.travis.yml` file.

In essence you tell `gpg` to not use the standard keyrings in the current user's home directory, but instead the keyrings you've just decrypted and stuck into your `$GPG_DIR`.

You may ask yourself where the other `<properties>`/env variables come from. They are appended to your `.travis.yml` when running the following commands:

```
$ travis encrypt --add -r <username>/<repository> SONATYPE_USERNAME=<sonatype username>
$ travis encrypt --add -r <username>/<repository> SONATYPE_PASSWORD=<sonatype password>
$ travis encrypt --add -r <username>/<repository> ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=<password to encrypt>
$ travis encrypt --add -r <username>/<repository> GPG_KEYNAME=<gpg keyname (ex. 1C06698F)>
$ travis encrypt --add -r <username>/<repository> GPG_PASSPHRASE=<gpg passphrase>
```

`<username>` is your Github username and `<repository>` your Github repo.
After running the `travis encrypt --add` commands, your `.travis.yml` file will have appended entries like this:

```
env:
  global:
  - GPG_DIR="`pwd`/deploy"
  - secure: 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
  - secure: 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
    [...]
```

These `secure` entries are translated to environment variables by Travis at build-time.

A couple more remarks:

- By default Travis uses gpg version 1. Because of issues with entering passphrases via loopback in gpg 2.0, version 1 is preferred. Once Travis supports gpg 2.2, this may change.
- If you haven't done so yet, you need to publish your key to

  1. http://keys.gnupg.net:11371
  2. http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371
  3. http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371

Good luck.